# Pegar a probabilidade de pertencer a cada classe

Tags: python, machine-learning, sklearn

Tenho um problema teórico onde um dono de loja quer saber qual a chance de determinada frase gerar uma venda, tenho em mãos um dicionário com 20 palavras aleatórias e 10 frases formadas por exatamente 10 palavras escolhidas aleatoriamente dentro do meu dicionário:

Dicionário de palavras :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Organizei minhas frases numa tabela e troquei as palavras por ID's para realizar um teste de classificação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu testei alguns algoritmos do sklearn e o que me deu o melhor resultado foi o CART:

```
treino_x, valid_x, treino_y, valid_y = (model_selection.train_test_split
                                        (x, y, test_size=valid, random_state=sementes))

pontuacao = 'accuracy'

modelos = []
modelos.append(('CART', DecisionTreeClassifier()))

resultado = []
nomes = []
for nome, modelo in modelos:
    kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=sementes)
    cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(modelo, treino_x, treino_y, cv=kfold, scoring=pontuacao)
    resultado.append(cv_results)
    nomes.append(nome)
    msg = "%s: %f (%f)" % (nome, cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std())
    print(msg)


cart = DecisionTreeClassifier()
cart.fit(treino_x, treino_y)
predictions = cart.predict(valid_x)
print(accuracy_score(valid_y, predictions))
```

Com isso eu já consigo simular uma nova frase qualquer e utilizar um `Cart.predict` para me dizer se essa frase é venda ou não, no entanto ao invés de apenas me retornar Venda / N eu gostaria de saber a probabilidade dessa frase ter gerado uma venda (Ex: 78%), nesse momento entra o peso de cada uma das features, como eu faço pra calcular esse peso utilizando o Python ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para saber a porcentagem de pertencer a cada classe, use a função [`.predict_proba()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#classification).

Ela é semelhante ao `.predict()`, mas retorna as probabilidades de pertencer a cada classe na forma de um array. Exemplo de retorno: `array([[0., 1.]])`, significa `0%` de chance de pertencer a classe `A` e `100%` de pertencer a classe `B`.

```
predictions = cart.predict_proba(valid_x)
```